# Ubuntu 10.10 DNS lookup failed

Tags: 10.10

I have an Ubuntu Meerkat(10.10) and my DNS fails.

I am connecting via proxy and I have set both $http_proxy variable and system wide settings for it.

When I try to ping 8.8.8.8 I get icmp response. However when I tried to ping www.google.com, it results in ping:unknown host google.com

I changed my /etc/resolv.conf file which had faulty nameservers. I gave:
domain xx.yy.com
search xx.yy.com
nameserver AA:BB:CC:DD

However as the Network manager is set, when I restart networking, the resolc.conf gets reset to some other nameserver.

I know I can set static dhcp and change the interfaces file but I would like to work with NM. So please advice!

Comment: I guess whenever I do sudo /sbin/dhclient, the DHCP changes the resolv.conf as well. Should I change dhclient.conf?

Comment: Welcome new visitors to this page.  It should be noted that "Support of Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat 10.10 was officially dropped on 10 April 2012".

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly configure network manager. Under ipv4 settings, select dhcp only and enter the name servers you wish to use.

You need to make sure then information you are entering is correct (AA:BB:CC:DD -> should that be AA.BB.CC.DD ?)

If you are entering the correct information , and resolv.conf is correct, did you enable your firewall (are you blocking dns traffic)?

[image: NM]

Comment: how do disable firewall?

Comment: I have a bigger problem at hand. Apart from wlan, eth0, eth1 is not even getting an IP from dhcp server.

Comment: The dhclient on eth0 results in: "There is already a pid file /var/run/dhclient.pid with pid 3306 killed old client process, removed PID file"... handshake messages and finally "No DHCPOFFERS recieved. No working leases in persistent database-sleeping"